# What is the word for people who deliberately listen to other people's talk?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want one word substitution for it.
I thought intruder but it is incorrect.

Answer (score 31):

That would be:
[Eavesdropper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eavesdrop?q=Eavesdropper#eavesdrop__8)

The verb eavesdrop is to:
"Secretly listen to a conversation"

(You didn't explicitly state that they were doing it surreptitiously but I assumed that it was implied by the nature of the question.)

Comment: That is an interesting word - eavesdrop. The OED has references for the noun, meaning the area close to a house, where water drops from the eaves, from as early as 868 (Kentish charter). But there is no reference to the verb - to *eavesdrop*, meaning to stand within the eaves drop to listen to the occupants speaking, until the 17th century.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, consider;

***overlistener***

> [overlisten](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22overlistened%22&biw=499&bih=327&prmd=imvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2n7uStbPJAhXIXhoKHW86CKwQ_AUICygG): *Rare* to listen so as to overhear or eavesdrop [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/overlisten) [Drexel University Library Services](https://services.library.drexel.edu/static_files/triangle/Drexel-Triangle_1978-03-10.pdf)

***prying ears*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prying+ears&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprying%20ears%3B%2Cc0)

> *Carmen shrugged at Katie's questioning look, and stepped through the door, closing it against prying ears.* [Your Dictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/prying#h3fKzLfrdYPx6iOO.99)

***listener-in***

> listen in (on)
>
> : to listen to a conversation between others; eavesdrop. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/listen+in)
>
> *Bystanders are those who are nearby, overhearers are possible
> interpreters and these include listener-ins (those that are attempting
> to listen) and eavesdroppers (those that are secretly listening)*
> [Google
> Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-eqXoNPXrzQC&pg=PA43&dq=%22listener-ins%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjag4PG-7LJAhXItBoKHa-4D4oQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22listener-ins%22&f=false)

***be a fly on the wall***

> : to surreptitiously listen to another person's conversation [Quotations Link](http://www.quotations.link/famous-idioms/84-fly-on-the-wall-idiom.htm)

***wiretapper***

> wiretap
>
> : (*n.*) an act of secretly listening to or recording a person's telephone or
> Internet conversations, often as part of a police investigation.
>
> : (*v.*) to listen in on by means of a wiretap. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wiretap)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an informal word for this you could try *earwig*. In this context *[earwig](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earwig)* is normally a verb:-

> 2. to eavesdrop [Collins English Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

but I have heard many times the person doing this referred to as an earwig.